# Will shredded mirror bush prunings create new mirror bush plants?

Tags: weeds, mulch

I have a large mirror bush (coprosma repens) that I want to remove, but I’m aware that it can be quite invasive, and that low hanging branches can strike new roots if they touch the soil.

If I shredded/chipped prunings from this tree/bush to create mulch, would there be any risk that new mirror bushes might spring up from the mulch?

Answer (score 1):

No, they won't if you are shredding/chipping them, but make sure to exclude any berries present before you shred. Branches from a living plant which touch the ground may root into the soil in a form of propagation called layering, but this only works because the branch which is rooting is still being supplied with nutrients from the main plant.